# How to rewrite language query to a more SEO friendly URL with nginx?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Basically I have a multiple language website. The URL of a selected language looks like this: website.com/?lang=EN

I have 30 languages. Is it possible to rewrite these URL's with applying a rewrite rule to cover them all to eg; website.com/en (website.com/"language")

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770685/rewrite-query-string-to-path-params

Answer (score 0):

check if the parameter exists and then use it for redirection, make sure to remove the parameter in your target url to avoid a redirect loop.

i.e. like this

```
if ($arg_lang!="") {
  rewrite ^/$ https://website.com/$arg_lang?;
}
```